# Convert Date to Milliseconds in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, milliseconds

I am trying to convert a date in `MySQL` to `milliseconds`. This is what I have to get the date:

```
DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(mydate)) DAY)
```

But that returns me like `15/02/2015` and I want to get the `milliseconds` of that date.

Comment: What do you mean by "the milliseconds of that date"? Milliseconds since the Unix epoch? Millseconds since some other time?

Comment: yes, since the Unix epoch

Comment: And what is the type of `mydate`? (You should edit your question to be a lot clearer...)

Comment: You should probably look at the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function though.

Answer (score 46):

Use the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function.

`SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mydate)*1000) FROM...`

UNIX_TIMESTAMP will get you seconds and you need to multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds.

To convert back, use FROM_UNIXTIME() function.

`SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date_in_milliseconds/1000) FROM ...`

Again, you need to divide by 1000 to get it to seconds before using the function.